# Hibernate mapping error for no apparent reason

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping

I am learning **hibernate** and followed exactly the same code from the book I'm following. I use `eclipse IDE` and `hibernate3` library. My database is `Oracle 11g` with only 1 table.

When I run project, I get following error:

```
Sep 03, 2021 11:26:41 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: Hibernate 3.2.6
Sep 03, 2021 11:26:41 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: hibernate.properties not found
Sep 03, 2021 11:26:41 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: Bytecode provider name : cglib
Sep 03, 2021 11:26:41 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
Sep 03, 2021 11:26:41 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Sep 03, 2021 11:26:41 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Sep 03, 2021 11:26:41 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: Reading mappings from resource : hibtest/Employee.hbm.xml
Failed to create sessionFactory object.org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource hibtest/Employee.hbm.xml
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at hibtest.ManageEmployee.main(ManageEmployee.java:17)
Caused by: org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource hibtest/Employee.hbm.xml
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:575)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:1593)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1561)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1540)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1514)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1434)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1420)
    at hibtest.ManageEmployee.main(ManageEmployee.java:14)
Caused by: org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from input stream
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addInputStream(Configuration.java:514)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:572)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: www.hibernate.org Nested exception: www.hibernate.org
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addInputStream(Configuration.java:505)
    ... 8 more
```

My Model class:

```
// Employee class
package hibtest;

public class Employee {
private int id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private int salary;

public Employee() {}

public Employee(String fname, String lname, int salary) {
this.firstName = fname;
this.lastName = lname;
this.salary = salary;
}

public int getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
this.id = id;
}

public String getFirstName() {  
return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String first_name) {
this.firstName = first_name;
}

public String getLastName() {
return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String last_name) {
this.lastName = last_name;
}

public int getSalary() {
return salary;
}

public void setSalary( int salary ) {
this.salary = salary;
}

}

// mapping file for Employee class
```

Hibernate mapping xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="Employee" table="EMPLOYEE">
<meta attribute="class-description">
This class contains the employee detail.
</meta>
<id name="id" type="int" column="id">
<generator class="native"/>
</id>
<property name="firstName" column="first_name" type="string"/>
<property name="lastName" column="last_name" type="string"/>
<property name="salary" column="salary" type="int"/>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

My hibernate config file is as under:-

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">
            oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
        </property>
        <property name="connection.url">
            jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.92.68.111:1521:MYSCHEMA
        </property>
        <property name="connection.username">
            TESTHIB
        </property>
        <property name="connection.password">
            testhib
        </property>

        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9iDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="max_fetch_depth">2</property>

        <property name="dialect" >
            org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9iDialect
        </property>

        <property name="jdbc.batch_size">0</property>
        <property name="cache.query_cache_factory">
            hibernatingrhinos.hibernate.profiler.cache.ProfilerQueryCacheFactory
        </property>
        <property name="generate_statistics">true</property>

        <!--  the only class  -->

        <mapping resource="hibtest/Employee.hbm.xml" />

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Table columns are exactly same i.e id, first_name , last_name and salary.

Comment: it seems that you've got a problem with hibernate configuration, could you please share your hibernate configuration file?!

Comment: *I am learning hibernate* Then don't use XML configuration. I've been using Hibernate for 12 years, and XML configuration was a legacy option even then. I've never used anything but Java annotations.

Comment: @mr1554 i have added hibernate configuration please

Answer (score 0):

Your mapping seems to be in order, but it seems there is an issue in resolving the DTD.

Hibernate uses the DTD to validate the XML mapping. The DTD is being retrieved following this: "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd" URL.
In some cases when hibernate is not able to retrieve the URL it will produce an error. Check if your system is able to connect to the URL. If the application has no access to the internet it should resolve the DTD via the classpath though. But if access is blocked e.g. via a captive portal it might give you this error.

Here you can find more information regarding hibernate mappings: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.2/reference/en/html/mapping.html